# Issue with PHP Email script

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form within one of my webpages, and i am now having trouble configuring it to the sendmail.php. When I fill in the form, and click submit, its asking me to save the file 'sendmail.php' but I want it to send to the email specified in the 'sendmail.php' file.

**in my 'sendmail.php' file I currently have:**

```
<?php 
$element_1_1 = $_POST['element_1_1'];
$element_1_2 = $_POST['element_1_2'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "sales@atechdigital.co.uk"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['element_4']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['element_1_1'];
$last_name = $_POST['element_1_2'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$message = $element_1_1 . " " . $element_1_2 . " Has Sent A Quote Request";

$element_2 = $_POST['element_2'];
$element_3 = $_POST['element_3'];
$element_4 = $_POST['element_4'];
$element_5_1 = $_POST['element_5_1'];
$element_5_2 = $_POST['element_5_2'];
$element_5_3 = $_POST['element_5_3'];
$element_5_4 = $_POST['element_5_4'];
$element_5_5 = $_POST['element_5_5'];
$element_5_6 = $_POST['element_5_6'];
  mail ($to,$element_4,$element_2,$element_3,$element_4,$element_5,$element_5_1,$element_5_2,$element_5_3,$element_5_4,$element_5_5,$element_5_6);
 echo " Thank you " . $first_name . ", One of our sales team is dealing with you're request! We will contact you shortly.";

}
?>
```

**and the html form is as follows:**

```
    <form id="form_824601" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="sendmail.php">                   
        <ul >

    <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_1_1" name= "element_1_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
        <label>First</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="element_1_2" name= "element_1_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
        <label>Last</label>
    </span> 
    </li>       

    <li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="element_2">Company Name </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       

    <li id="li_3" >
    <label class="description" for="element_3">Enter Contact Telephone Number </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       

    <li id="li_4" >
    <label class="description" for="element_4">Enter Email Address </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
    </li>       

    <li id="li_5" >
    <label class="description" for="element_5">Request A Quote For ... </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_5_1" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_1">Web Design</label>
<input id="element_5_2" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_2">SEO</label>
<input id="element_5_3" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_3">Social Media</label>
<input id="element_5_4" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="4" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_4">Graphic Design</label>
<input id="element_5_5" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="5" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_5">Video Marketing</label>
<input id="element_5_6" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="6" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_6">Maintenance</label>

    </span> 
    </li>

    <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="824601" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

**I Hope someone can shed light on the issue I'm having!!**

Comment: Are you running in both the files inside htdocs ?

Comment: Your webserver is not opening the .php file.

Comment: Also what @SulthanAllaudeen said, are you trying to open this in your browser from your disk (with double click, not with http://)?

Comment: I'm just running it in a folder on my desktop?

Comment: Then you can't run it. You should install a webserver (xampp or wampp) and then put your files inside the htdocs inside the xampp or wampp folder and then run that file.

Comment: I have the site on a live domain, can i test it on that?

Comment: @AtechDigitalMedia yes you could

Comment: P.S. Have you heard of `naming convention`?

Comment: Thank you! I shall try that now!

Comment: I havent heard of naming convention? I'm new to the php script

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29 definitely worth a read. It's more general programming / scripting practice than specific to php.

Comment: When naming your different fields, you have named them e.g. Element_1 and so on - you should aim  to give all your fields and variables a specific name so as to avoid confusion later on and improve readability for yourself and anyone else who uses your code. An example would be renaming your Element_1 to name, Element_2 to companyName etc

Comment: @AtechDigitalMedia do you have a webserver running with php configured?

Comment: I've just tried it on my testing domain and works perfectly! Thanks Guys!!

Comment: I recommend you read this article http://mattgeri.com/2012/01/escaping-input-to-the-php-mail-function/ and you could also have a look into https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer - using code intended for tutorial purposes is often vulnerable to security risks and abuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work while you are running the script locally. You need to run it on a server that can handle PHP. The only way you could run it locally and that is if you have a local web server set up.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run .php files just from the folder, you will need a web server to handle it for you. if you are running windows or mac , you can set one up using software like XAMPP (win + osx) , WAMP (win) , MAMP (osx).

If you happen you run a linux distribution, you can set up a LAMP server.

Here are some links: 
https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
http://www.wampserver.com/en/
http://www.mamp.info/en/

From the links above, xampp has always worked out the best for me performance wise. parsing a huge xml feed and putting it into a mysql database takes like half the time on xampp compared to wamp.